# Wiring help for a DC LVDT?

Tags: arduino, sensor, wiring

I have a DC LVDT here with a built in signal conditioner:
http://www.te.com/usa-en/product-CAT-LVDT0004.html

I have a weak background in electronics, so I really have no clue who I'm supposed to extract signals from this sensor. Ideally I would want it hooked up with an arduino. Anyways, three wires:

Red: +VCC (Loop supply Input)
Black: -LOW (Loop supply Return)
Green: Case Ground

Any help on setting this up would be much appreciated!

Comment: Treat it as any other 4-20mA signalling devire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume you've read through [the datasheet](http://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=showdoc&DocId=Data%20Sheet%7FSI%7FA%7Fpdf%7FEnglish%7FENG_DS_SI_A.pdf%7FCAT-LVDT0004). [Here](https://www.phidgets.com/docs/4-20mA_Sensor_Interface_Primer#4-20mA_Sensor_Interface) is a decent article on 4-20mA sensors and how to work with them. Notice that you need to provide something between 10 V and 28 V DC to operate this sensor, which is not going to be particularly "Arduino-friendly," but you can use an interface module to convert the sensor response to a 0-5V signal. You can also roll your own using a trans-impedance amplifier circuit, but I'm thinking you'll do better with off-the-shelf tech, maybe something like [this](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/8883), which integrates an Allegro ACS712 current sensor.

As for what to do with the chassis ground... I would connect it to your system ground (i.e. the Arduino ground).

And you'd wire it something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdM8oc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks so much! This clears a lot of things up, I will definitely take a look at that primer you supplied.